# Zend framework dynamic breadcrumbs lable

Tags: php, zend-framework

Hey, I have got the Zend navigation in in navigation.xml which is like this:

```
<nav>
    <home>
        <label>Home</label>
        <controller>index</controller>
        <resource>index</resource>
        <action>index</action>
        <pages>
            <Reports>
                <label>Reports</label>
                    <controller>Reports</controller>
                    <resource>Reports</resource>
                    <action>index</action>
            </Reports>
        </pages>
    </home>
</nav>
```

and I have initialized my breadcrumbs through

```
$this->navigation()->breadcrumbs()
```

That works fine as far as the page is in the navigation.xml but what I want is, for example there is a Report with the name of "Today Report" then the breadcrumb should look like: Home > Reports > Today's Report , in other words dynamic breadcrumbs, is there already a way of doing that? or should I implement my own? should I ditch XML and should use the array for navigation which is then all built dynamically from database and then store the object into registry? but then again I do not want all that to appear in navigation, it should be only for breadcrumbs. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to change your xml to the following:

```
<nav>
    <home>
        <label>Home</label>
        <controller>index</controller>
        <resource>index</resource>
        <action>index</action>
        <pages>
            <Reports>
                <label>Reports</label>
                <controller>Reports</controller>
                <resource>Reports</resource>
                <action>index</action>
                <pages>
                    <TodayReport>
                        <label>Today Report</label>
                        <controller>Reports</controller>
                        <action>today-report</action>
                                            <visible>0</visible>
                    </TodayReport>
                </pages>
            </Reports>
        </pages>
    </home> </nav>
```

The Today report will be hidden due (0), but to enable them for the breadcrumbs use the following:
$this->navigation()->breadcrumbs()->setRenderInvisible(TRUE);

You can generate a navigation object from the database, this is not explained itself in the documentation but you can find out how to create a navigation object their. http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.navigation.pages.html

Comment: Awesome! This is the exact issue I was having.  I wanted to hide the option from the main nav, have the pages appear in my sitemap, but also include the breadcrumbs on the page (which were hidden until now).  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If it is just about the breadcrumbs, not the sitemap, do not render the last element and use the title, you are probably already displaying on the page:

```
<?= $this->navigation()->breadcrumbs()->setMinDepth(0) . ' > ' . $this->title ?>
```

Otherwise, you have to iterate the container and perform replace manually.